# magento2 invoice paid status

Tags: magento2, invoice

I'm creating an invoice module for Magento2 and I've got my custom payment method setup and working. (Customers can select it, it does its things and works, etc)

I'm stuck on the next step though, and what I want to happen is that when the administrator in the back-end generates an invoice the status for the invoice should be "Unpaid" and not the default "Paid". The administrator then prints out the invoice, sends to the customer, and when they receive the payment they should be able to change it to Paid manually and complete the order.

I assume I should start somewhere by extending adminhtml in one of the default magento modules but I'm not sure where. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add Unpaid status in magento Admin Panel(or by the migration script), and you should set it as default to processing state.

take a look on those tables:

```
sales_order_status
sales_order_status_history
sales_order_status_label
sales_order_status_state
```